# The controller for URI is not callable. Controller does neither exist as service nor as class

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting the error in the title when trying to call a controller.

Here's my configuration:

**config/services.yaml**

```
parameters:
  locale: 'en'
  localhost_base_url: '%env(string:localhost_base_url)%'

services:
  # default configuration for services in *this* file
  _defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    public: false

  # makes classes in src/MlngAppBundle/ available to be used as services
  # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
  MlngApp\MlngAppBundle\:
    resource: '../src/MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/*'
    exclude:
      - '../src/MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/MlngAppBundle.php'
      - '../src/MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/{Common,Event,Location,People,User}/Domain/{Entity,Dto,Exception,Invariant}/*'
      - '../src/MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/{Common,Event,Location,People,User}/Tests/*'
      - '../src/MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/{Common,Event,Location,People,User}/Infrastructure/CommandLine/*'
```

**config/packages/config.yaml**

```
imports:
- { resource: domains/* }
- { resource: "@MlngAppBundle/Common/Infrastructure/Resources/config/services.xml" }
- { resource: "@MlngAppBundle/Location/Infrastructure/Resources/config/services.xml" }
```

And the "Common" services.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>

        <!-- repository classes -->
        <prototype
                namespace="MlngApp\MlngAppBundle\"
                resource="../../../../../../../src/MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/{Common,Event,Location,People,User}/Infrastructure/Repository/"
                autoconfigure="true"
                autowire="true"
                public="true"
        >
            <tag name="doctrine.repository_service"/>
        </prototype>

        <!-- repository interface classes -->
        <prototype
                namespace="MlngApp\MlngAppBundle\"
                resource="../../../../../../../src/MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/{Common,Event,Location,People,User}/Domain/Repository/"
                autoconfigure="true"
                autowire="true"
                public="true"
        >
            <tag name="doctrine.repository_service"/>
        </prototype>

        <!-- controllers -->
        <prototype
                namespace="MlngApp\MlngAppBundle\"
                resource="../../../../../../../src/MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/{Common,Event,Location,People,User}/Api/Controller"
        >
            <tag name="controller.service_arguments" />
            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            </call>
        </prototype>

    </services>
</container>
```

Concerning routes, I have:

**config/routes.yaml**

```
location:
  resource: "@MlngAppBundle/Location/Api/Resources/config/routing.xml"
  prefix: /api
  type: xml
```

and

**@MlngAppBundle/Location/Api/Resources/config/routing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd"
>
    <import resource="routing/location.xml" prefix="/location"/>

    <route id="testingstuff" path="/donothing" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/Location/Api/Controller/AnotherController::anotherEndpoint</default>
    </route>
</routes>
```

and the controller:

```
<?php

namespace MlngApp\MlngAppBundle\Location\Api\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AnotherController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function anotherEndpoint(Request $request) {
        echo "do nothing";
    }
}
```

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/donothing I get

**The controller for URI "/api/donothing" is not callable: Controller "MlngApp/MlngAppBundle/Location/Api/Controller/AnotherController" does neither exist as service nor as class.**

I understand that it means the AnotherController class is undefined but it gets defined in services.yaml and services.xml

Using Symfony 5.4

I don't know where to look for any clue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yikes.  At the risk of being overly technical, this looks like a mess.  Are you following a tutorial?  Is this a project that used to work?  In general bundles are in charge of defining their own services.  Trying to autowire from the application's config/services.yaml file can work but it just confuses things in this case.  In any event, does `bin/console debug:container AnotherController` show a service?

Comment: Thanks, @Cerad.

Yes, the controller as service shows the service id, class and public, autowired and autoconfigured as true.                                                          

It's a brand new project.

Comment: And is the service id the class name or something like 'another.controller'.  And I know it is off-topic but the FOS stuff has pretty much gone away.  Did you look at the api-platform before selecting FOSRestBundle?

Comment: If those comments are to be trusted (specially the "creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name") and the setup works, I'd say your routing file is wrong: use backslashes as namespace separators in the controller name.

Comment: @msg Good catch on those forward slashes.  I thought something looked strange but it must have been a forest/tree sort of thing.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks, I don't blame you, I also see some alarms going off with that configuration but I forced myself to focus on the problem at hand but still, I began my comment with a big "if". Given that includes _are processes first_, wouldn't the default `resources:` overwrite the custom service configuration? In other words, except for the routing I don't think all that configuration is doing anything, but I'm not 100% sure, I can't keep all those paths straight in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, people.

@msg, you were right. I'm using the incorrect backslashes. I am a bit ashamed since this is kind of rookie mistakes. Shame on me.

In `@MlngAppBundle/Location/Api/Resources/config/routing.xml` it should be

```
        <default key="_controller">MlngApp\MlngAppBundleLocation\Api\Controller\AnotherController::anotherEndpoint</default>
```

Working now.

As a side note, I'm trying this configuration as a way to work with DDD with an arquitectural design proposed in https://www.fabian-keller.de/blog/domain-driven-design-with-symfony-a-folder-structure/

Again, thanks @Cerad and @msg for your time and advices. :)

Comment: Glad you got past the issue.  I remember reading the 2106 article you linked to.  Sometimes I think software architectures get paid based on the number of directories they create.

Answer (score 1):

For me i've added "use 'Name_Space'" of my controller in the entity and it works!!